# How to read the result table of BenchmarkDotNet

Tags: c#, .net, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

I ran a [benchmark example](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) and got this table.

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.0, OS=Windows 7 SP1 (6.1.7601.0)
Intel Xeon CPU E5-4660 v3 2.10GHz, 1 CPU, 28 logical and 14 physical cores
Frequency=2050214 Hz, Resolution=487.7540 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.8 (4.8.4018.0), X86 LegacyJIT  [AttachedDebugger]
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.8 (4.8.4018.0), X86 LegacyJIT


| Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|
| Sha256 | 173.60 us | 3.466 us | 9.604 us |
|    Md5 |  29.95 us | 0.599 us | 1.709 us |
```

Well... How to read it?

What is the actual meaning of [ **Mean** | **Error** | **StdDev** ] ?

I'm new to this...

I can't find any reference for this..

Anyone can provide a link that explains this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get this information from author of `BenchmarkDotNet` [blog post](https://aakinshin.net/posts/stephen-toub-benchmarks-part1/)

```
  Mean      : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error     : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev    : Standard deviation of all measurements
```

Comment: Thanks! - Btw, can I ask a simple question - does the **higher mean** (or Error / stddev) means higher CPU power? (or the opposite)

Comment: @AkutaHinako that question is unclear. As for Error, Stddev, that's statistics, it says *nothing* about CPU power. It says how good the measurement is. High error is bad. For the rest, you should really read the statistics links posted in the comments

Comment: @AkutaHinako The lower value means the faster calculation of particular test